# what is the most efficient way to open osm.pbf' with lowest memory consumption?

Tags: python, pandas, openstreetmap

Here's what I did

```
from pyrosm import OSM
# Initialize the OSM parser object
osm = OSM('/DATA/user/nabih/indonesia-latest.osm.pbf')

# Read all drivable roads
drive_net = osm.get_network(network_type="driving")
```

But it is memory error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://osmcode.org/pyosmium/ provides a library to parse a osm.pbf. From what I remember, they keep the memory consumption to the minimum and provide different modes of parsing.

Checkout their [`documentation`](https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/) for basic usage tutorial and references.

The README of their [`GitHub`](https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium)provides installation instructions.